# Unable to send mail by gmail smtp: keeps waiting for localhost?

Tags: c#

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SmtpClient mail = new SmtpClient();
        mail.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        mail.Host="smtp.gmail.com";
        mail.Port=465;
        mail.Credentials=new NetworkCredential("b.soham1991","*******");
        mail.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        mail.EnableSsl = true;

        mail.Timeout = 1000000;

        mail.Send("b.soham1991@gmail.com", "soham.elf@gmail.com", "Hi", "via gmail");
        Response.Write("success!");
    }
```

`Reponse.Write` is never exeuted and eventually connection is timed out. what am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure that the reason it is not executed is because it's not working? Because if you somehow failed to send the mail and are waiting for the 1,000,000 ms timeout, it could also be a big problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong port.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SmtpClient mail = new SmtpClient();
    mail.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    mail.Host="smtp.gmail.com";
    mail.Port=587; //new port!
    mail.UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    mail.Credentials=new NetworkCredential("b.soham1991","*******");
    mail.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    mail.EnableSsl = true;

    mail.Timeout = 1000000;

    mail.Send("b.soham1991@gmail.com", "soham.elf@gmail.com", "Hi", "via gmail");
    Response.Write("success!");
}
```

Additionally, be sure to use `System.Net.Mail` and not `System.Web.Mail`

Refer to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail) for a detailed and refined answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept my post as the answer by clicking the check symbol left to my post

Answer (score 0):

You should try to assign to a label for instace.

Add a label to the form.

The you can simply.

```
labelstatus.text = "success!";
```

Can you maybe add `Exception` handler to this to see exactly where it goes wrong in case the `mail` object never completes?